# Fullcalendar - Add icon to event with eventRender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add an svg icon using `import { GoMail } from "react-icons/go";`. Unfortunately I can't seem to find an accurate way to add this to my injected html elements. Besides, I have the following error:

> arg.el.find is not a function

Which type I should use for el parameter in typescript and how can I work with react-icons for Fullcalendar?

```
onEventRender = (arg: {event: EventApi; el: HTMLElement; view: View;}) => {
    const start = arg.event.start ? moment(arg.event.start).format('LT') : null
    const end = arg.event.end ? moment(arg.event.end).format('LT') : null
    const event:any = arg.event
    const eventRecurrenceType = event.extendedProps.recurrenceType

    if (eventRecurrenceType) {

        const icon = <GoMail/>;
        arg.el.find('.noteContainer').append(icon);

        const notes = `<div class=${styles.noteContainer}>
                        <div class=${styles.numberOfNotes}>20</div>
                        <div class=${styles.noteIcon}>${icon}</div>
                       </div>`

        const eventDetails = `<div class=${styles.eventContainer}> 
                                <div>${start}-${end}</div>
                                ${notes}
                              </div>`

        const title = `<div class=${styles.eventTitle}>${arg.event.title}</div>`

        const recurrence = `<div>${eventRecurrenceType}</div>`

        arg.el.innerHTML = eventDetails + title + recurrence
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `.find()` is a [jQuery function](https://api.jquery.com/find/). `arg.el` is not a jQuery object, it's a standard DOM element. You'd have to wrap that in a jQuery constructor if you want to use jQuery functions on it. `$(arg.el).find(`... (assuming you've got jQuery loaded in your page).